# Laying out elements in varying height in three columns in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout

I would like to lay out some elements in CSS which "flow" vertically in three or four columns, which would look like this :

[image]

The layout should put elements in the columns as evenly as possible.

A normal grid layout wouldn't work because of the vertical grid lines, and flexbox doesn't seem to offer anything with its column flow direction.

Does anyone have an idea for a good approach to laying out elements like this?

Comment: the name of this layout is "masonry", there are tons of tutorials on the internet to implement this

Comment: as far as I can tell there is no CSS solution for this, except for some Grid layout configuration that doesnt work in 99% of browsers. So the only way to solve this is to use a javascript library (i used react-responsive-masonry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the sequence you want the elements to be displayed.

If you’re happy for the sequence to be column 1 top to bottom, followed by column 2 top to bottom, followed by column 3 top to bottom, then you can use CSS’s often-overlooked [multi-column layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). Just style the wrapper with `columns: 3`.

```js
let s = ''
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 25
  s += `<div style="border-color: hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%); background-color: hsl(${hue}, 50%, 97%); height: ${height}px;">${i + 1}</div>`
}
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = s
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  columns: 3;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  break-inside: avoid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

If instead you want the first three elements to be displayed at the top of columns 1, 2 and 3, and then element 4 to be displayed in whichever column is the shortest, then that’s a **masonry layout**. Direct support for this in CSS [is being worked on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Masonry_layout#), but in the meantime there are [various techniques you can try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout).